# Remove vertical bar only on first page (Marburg theme)

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am using the Marburg theme in latex to have a vertical bar showing my sections.

In the first page dedicated to the title I would like to remove the bar keeping the top and bottom bar.

I know the option `plain` will remove the side bar, but this will remove all bars.

Do you know how can I realize my goal?

My code:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdftex}]{beamer}
\useoutertheme{shadow}
\usetheme[left]{Marburg}

\definecolor{ceruleanblue}{rgb}{0.16, 0.32, 0.75}
\definecolor{caribbeangreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.8, 0.6}
\definecolor{darkpastelgreen}{rgb}{0.01, 0.75, 0.24}

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}[vertical shading][top=ceruleanblue,middle=darkpastelgreen,bottom=ceruleanblue] 

\colorlet{titleleft}{ceruleanblue}
\colorlet{titlemiddle}{darkpastelgreen}
\colorlet{titleright}{ceruleanblue}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titlemiddle,titleright]
{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{
color(0pt)=(titleleft);
color(0.6\paperwidth)=(titlemiddle);
color(\paperwidth)=(titleright)
}


\title[aa]{aa}
\date{\today}


\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Large, series=\bf}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\footnotesize}


\author[bla]
{
\textbf{bla}\inst{1}, bla\inst{2}, bla\inst{3}}

\institute[]
{
\inst{1 }bla \\
\inst{2 }bla\\
\inst{ 3}bla
}



\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{parent=palette primary,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{parent=palette secondary,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary,bg=}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=palette primary,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{parent=palette secondary,bg=}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
\leavevmode%
\setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}%
\beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
\advance\beamer@tempdim by 4pt%
\begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{20pt}
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
\pgfusepath{clip}
\pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
\end{pgfpicture}
\vskip-\beamer@tempdim%
\box\beamer@tempbox%    
}%

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
\leavevmode%
\setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}%
\beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
\advance\beamer@tempdim by 4pt%
\vskip-\beamer@tempdim%
\begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{20pt}
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
\pgfusepath{clip}
\pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
\end{pgfpicture}
\vskip-\beamer@tempdim%
\box\beamer@tempbox%    
\vskip0pt%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{titlepage}
\end{titlepage}
\end{frame}


\section{ble}
\subsection{bla}
\begin{frame}{Slide 1}
Content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format that may be a bit different from other sites.

Answer (score 1):

You could temporarily redefine the `sidebar canvas left` and `sidebar left` templates:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdftex}]{beamer}
\useoutertheme{shadow}
\usetheme[left]{Marburg}

\definecolor{ceruleanblue}{rgb}{0.16, 0.32, 0.75}
\definecolor{caribbeangreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.8, 0.6}
\definecolor{darkpastelgreen}{rgb}{0.01, 0.75, 0.24}

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}[vertical shading][top=ceruleanblue,middle=darkpastelgreen,bottom=ceruleanblue] 

\colorlet{titleleft}{ceruleanblue}
\colorlet{titlemiddle}{darkpastelgreen}
\colorlet{titleright}{ceruleanblue}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titlemiddle,titleright]
{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{
color(0pt)=(titleleft);
color(0.6\paperwidth)=(titlemiddle);
color(\paperwidth)=(titleright)
}


\title[aa]{aa}
\date{\today}


\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Large, series=\bf}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\footnotesize}


\author[bla]
{
\textbf{bla}\inst{1}, bla\inst{2}, bla\inst{3}}

\institute[]
{
\inst{1 }bla \\
\inst{2 }bla\\
\inst{ 3}bla
}



\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{parent=palette primary,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{parent=palette secondary,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary,bg=}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=palette primary,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{parent=palette secondary,bg=}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
\leavevmode%
\setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}%
\beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
\advance\beamer@tempdim by 4pt%
\begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{20pt}
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
\pgfusepath{clip}
\pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
\end{pgfpicture}
\vskip-\beamer@tempdim%
\box\beamer@tempbox%    
}%

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
\leavevmode%
\setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}%
\beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
\advance\beamer@tempdim by 4pt%
\vskip-\beamer@tempdim%
\begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{20pt}
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
\pgfusepath{clip}
\pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
\end{pgfpicture}
\vskip-\beamer@tempdim%
\box\beamer@tempbox%    
\vskip0pt%
}


\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{}
\begin{frame}
\hspace{-.5\beamersidebarwidth}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\maketitle
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
}

\section{ble}
\subsection{bla}
\begin{frame}{Slide 1}
Content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Another thing: do you how can I show the short title at the bottom but not in lateral bar?

Comment: @jin If you have a new question, ask a new question

Comment: ...is only a little doubt...i can't understand your rigidity

Comment: @jin Changing the short title might or might not be something simple, but the purpose of this site is to build a library of knowledge. If a future user has the same question, they won't be able to find it hidden in some comment. In a new question, future users with the same problem have a chance to find the solution (which would require that the question is not immediately deleted...)